# Haversine Formula still not working

Tags: javascript

I used harversine formula to calculate if points are inside/outside of circle, but still it response that points are inside of the circle, it must be outside the circle. Take a look at my code.

```
    var xp = 7.070562277980709;  // point_lat
    var yp = 125.60755640475463;  // point_long
    var radius = 63.942490126300555;  // radius
    var xc = 7.070479805752504;  // circle_lat
    var yc = 125.60851603754577; // circle_lon

    var r       =   radius / 1000; // convert meter to kilometer
    var dlat    =   (xp - xc) * (Math.PI / 180);
    var dlng    =   (yp - yc) * (Math.PI / 180);
    var a       =   ((Math.sin(dlat / 2)) * (Math.sin(dlat / 2)));
    var b       =   ((Math.cos(xp * (Math.PI / 180))) * (Math.cos(xc * (Math.PI / 180))));
    var c       =   ((Math.sin(dlng / 2)) * (Math.sin(dlng / 2)));
    var d       =   a + (b * c);

    var e       =   2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(d), Math.sqrt(1 - d));
    var f       =   r * e;
    if (f < r) {
        alert('INSIDE');
    } else if(f > r) {
        alert('OUTSIDE');
    }
```

this function should alert me "OUTSIDE". Whats wrong with this code?? Thanks for your help.

All points are given by google map. And the default unit of radius of google map is meter, thats why I converted it to kilometer.

Comment: Must who use SI units use meters to measure metres. ;-)

Comment: can you modify my code so I can understand what are you talking about? thanks .. please :'(

Comment: Your code seems correct. And distance unit does not matter. What is the basis of your assumption of expected output?

Comment: if the distance is lesser than the radius, must the point is inside the circle. so, why is it the output always prompt me INSIDE, it should be OUTSIDE?

Comment: This code looks like it computes `f`, the distance between a point at `(xp,yp)` to `(xc,yc)` on a sphere of radius `r`.

Answer (score 1):

In the formula you are using, the radius is the Earth's radius. The formula gives the great circle (i.e. shortest) distance between two points on the Earth's surface.

Using 63.942490126300555 for the radius, then dividing it by 1,000 gives an *f* of 0.0000010667905687961212 km or 0.001 m or 1 mm.

Substituting a more appropriate value for *r* (e.g. 6,371) gives an *f* of 0.10629117978319975 km, or 106.291 metres.

Calculating it another way, since the coordinates are close to the equator, you can work out the distances as fractions of the Earth's circumference and use plain trigonometry.

Using a circumference of 40,000 km, the difference in latitude is 0.0000824722282057877 degrees, which is:

```
dLat = 40,000 km * 0.0000824722282057877 / 360
```

or

```
dLat = 0.009163580911754189 km
     = 9.164 m
```

and for longitude:

```
dLong = 0.0009596327911367553;
dist  = 40000 * 0.0009596327911367553 / 360;
      = 0.10662586568186169 km
      = 106.626 m
```

And a bit of basic trig:

```
dist = sqrt(9.164^2 + 106.626^2)
     = 0.10629117978319975 km
     = 106.291 m
```

which is pretty close to the other result. You can use that method quite successfully for small distances, just multiply the distance derived from the difference in longitude by the cosine of the latitude (since angular distances get shorter as you get closer to the pole).

My comment was just a dig at your spelling of "metre". :-)

#### Edit

Here's a function to return the great circle distance based on the Haversine formula at [Movable Type Scripts](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html):

```
// Return the great circle distance between two points on
// the Earth's surface given their latitude and longitude in
// decimal degrees. Only approximate.
function greatCircleDistance(lat0, lon0, lat1, lon1) {

  // Approximate Earth radius
  var earthRadius = 6.371e3;  // 6,371,000 m

  // Convert args to radians
  for (var i=arguments.length; i; ) {
    arguments[--i] = arguments[i] * Math.PI/180;
  }

  // Do calculation
  var dLat = lat1 - lat0;
  var dLon = lon1 - lon0;

  var a = Math.pow(Math.sin(dLat/2),2) +
          Math.cos(lat0) * Math.cos(lat1) *
          Math.pow(Math.sin(dLon/2),2);

  var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1 - a));

  return earthRadius * c;
}

var xp = 7.070562277980709;   // point_lat
var yp = 125.60755640475463;  // point_long

var xc = 7.070479805752504;   // circle_lat
var yc = 125.60851603754577;  // circle_lon

console.log(greatCircleDistance(xp, yp, xc, yc)); // 0.10629117978188952
```

So you can do:

```
if ( greatCircleDistance(xp, yp, xc, yc) > 63) { 
  console.log('outside');
} else {
  console.log('inside');
}
```

Comment: I want to validate if points are inside/outside of the given radius. In my given example, the result should be OUTSIDE, because the points are not inside of the circle. In your given example the result is also INSIDE, why?

Comment: where did you get this result 0.0000824722282057877??

Comment: @trishawhite—in your OP, there is no circle. The radius is the radius of the sphere that the points are all on the surface of (i.e. the radius of the Earth). That number is `xp - xc` (i.e. the difference in latitude). Note that latitude equates to the y direction in a cartesian system, not x (which equates to longitude). Lines of latitude indicate places of equal latitude and run horizontally, but they're graduated north–south, just like a y axis.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that your Harversine calculation is correct and it is equal to the result returned by [google map api static method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#spherical) **computeDistanceBetween**. Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Amitesh_Bharat/9rmLafew/2/).

However your logic implies that both the radius of sphere and radius within which you want to check if a point exists, are same.
To get the expected output you must model your problem space as below

- **R :** radius of sphere
- **p1, p2... :** points(lat,long co-ordinates) on the surface of sphere
- **r:** to check whether p2 lies within distance 'r' of p1 where r & R in the same unit

Based on above you need to implement below logic

```
var e = calculate haversine of the central angle for point p1 and p2  
var d = e * R;//where R is the radius of sphere, and the d would be great circle distance
if( d < r){// check whether p1 exists within r distance of p2
  //point is inside
}
else{
    //point is outside
}
```

Note that Haversine formula is not only for earth distance, rather it is for spherical body. However the correctness may differ based on size and position of the points under consideration.

Comment: even though I used the 51.656398773-lat and -121.2880020144-long, the result still INSIDE, why?

Comment: Thanks RobG for your insight in the implied question requirement.

Comment: Cool, glad to see you got it. ;-)